# extjs-how to find the grid column width

Tags: extjs

Is there a way to find the grid column width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(If you are using 3.3.1)

Assuming `var grid = your grid;`, you can use `grid.getColumnModel().getColumnWidth(n)` to get the width of a column, and use the event `widthchange` if you need to listen to the width changes.

Check the documentation, of class `ColumnModel`, and its method `getColumnWidth` and event `widthchange`.